# Can't get my wired connection to work

Tags: internet, network-manager, ethernet, connection, wired

Wireless works fine without any problem, but wired connection is not working for me.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

I have tried to follow a number of different topics, mainly these; http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1504618, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1494628. But so far, still no connection with my cable.

I have edited these files quite a bit because everyone is giving different instructions for similar issues, however I cant seem to get it right. Please someone help me out..

**ifconfig:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:22:0b:b0:91:3e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2424 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2424 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:241074 (241.0 KB)  TX bytes:241074 (241.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:d2:24:3d:bc:42  
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4ad2:24ff:fe3d:bc42/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10494 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8782 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8283223 (8.2 MB)  TX bytes:1409996 (1.4 MB)
```

**/etc/network/interfaces:**

```
 #This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
 #and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

 #The loopback network interface
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
 address 127.0.0.1
 netmask 255.0.0.0

 #The primary network interface
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**/etc/resolv.conf:**

```
 #Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
 #DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
 nameserver 127.0.1.1
 nameserver 192.168.0.1
 nameserver 94.208.107.35
 #search WL309
```

Comment: how about your cable? Is it a crossover one or a straight one? To connect to a switch is better the straight, to connect an access point sometimes work only the crossover one.

Comment: Neither works. The wired connection works fine on my pc however my laptop does not recognize it.

Comment: sure, but that shall depend on NIC Auto-MDIX ability of the PC nic. Please check the cable pin, if the order of the small green and orange cables is inverted between the connectors, that's means is a crossover cable, the correct one to connect a pc to an access point.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood, did you use a crossover?

Comment: It has wires in the following order: Brown - White - Green - White - Blue - White - Orange - White.

Is this the information you need?

Comment: If the pinning (the order of the colors) is the same on each connector, you are using a straight cable (the wrong one). You have to try with a crossover cable, that have the position of the green and the orange cable of one connector inverted respect the other one. That look like a so little thing, but also I was in your situation and that was the cause :)

Comment: Edit: depend on what are you connecting the laptop: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: I have 11 cables in my house, 5 of which are mine. They are all exactly the same colorwise regarding the orange and green.. So ye..

Answer (score 0):

Your eth0 device doesn't have an IP address.  Check the /etc/network/interfaces and make sure it has something like the following.

```
auto lo eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If it doesn't have that, add it and save the file.  Then run -

```
service networking restart
```

Comment: My /etc/network/interfaces file looks as follows:

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp